# <~ in elm 0.16.0 gives me a compile time error

Tags: elm

Very new to Elm but wanted to play around with the `<~` operator. It seems when I run elm-make, `<~` it is not recognized as an operator, and I get the error

> Cannot find variable `<~`

Has this been deprecated ( I see it in the docs at [elm-lang.org/docs/syntax#mapping](http://elm-lang.org/docs/syntax#mapping) ). Am I just using it incorrectly? Here is my code snippet that will not compile-

```
sqrtSig : Signal number
sqrtSig = sqrt <~ Mouse.x
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `<~` and `~` [were removed](https://github.com/elm-lang/core/commit/22dd8695c12566ef132c6ba6a97453e883de51ae) following [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/elm-discuss/gOU1yxAgWA8/raqfieuLCQAJ)

Comment: thanks - confusing that the docs still list them but I guess they are referring to the previous versions

Comment: Since those operators are removed in 0.16, I'll add them to the 0.16 version of elm-signal-extra. I probably have time to update the package to 0.16 this weekend.

Comment: Cool - I really liked those operators and thought they even looked nice from an aesthetic perspective. i was bummed to learn they were removed.

Comment: @user772110 If you didn't see it yet: the [new version of my library](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/Apanatshka/elm-signal-extra/5.7.0/) has been released.